# Getting hold of which dynamically generated PHP variable has been clicked and display on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic, bootstrap-modal

I'm developing a messaging system and I have a list of items that are generated dynamically from a database using PHP.

All of these items have an associated message button and I need to know which one has been clicked and pass through the ID of this item to a message box that appears on the screen upon click of the message button.

I thought about using a form with hidden values to post, but this doesnt work as the page refreshes and I've used javascript to get the message box to popup too. document.getelementbyid also didn't help as the ID's of the items are generated dynamically. I read online I could do this using Ajax but couldn't get it to work with my code either.

Thanks in advance and apologies if this has already been asked but I've been searching for about half an hour and couldn't find any posts asking the same as my scenario.

```
    <?php for ($j = 0; $j < $counter; $j++) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 item">
            <div class="box">
                <a href="itemdetails.php?id=<?php echo $itemIDDB[$j];?>">
                <h3 class="name"><?php echo $itemNameDB[$j]?></h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"><img class="img-rounded profileimage" src="<?php echo $imageURLS[$j];?>"></div>
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="price"><?php echo "£" . $priceDB[$j]; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="condition"><?php if ($conditionDB[$j] == 11) { echo "NEW"; } else { echo $conditionDB[$j]; } ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs messagebutton" data-id="<?php echo $usernameDB[$i] ?>" type="button">message</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="username"><?php echo $usernameDB[$i] ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="description"><?php echo $descriptionDB[$j]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
```

^^ Above is the code that generates each item and I need to pass the item ID to display instead of '

#### message username

' in the code below. All this code is in the same file.

```
    <div id="messagenewuser">
    <h3>Message username</h3>
    <form method="post" class=".messagepopup">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" form="userreviewform" maxlength="50"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" id="submitreview">send</button>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control hidden" type="text" name="tradeID">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there javascript code somewhere to handle clicks? If so, can you edit your post to have it?

Comment: you have a button element, a button element will not submit any form I think. How are you saying that it's submitting? do you have any javascript that processes your form?

Comment: There is javascript code, but it just adds display block and display none when appropriate. I did put the button in a form, but I removed the form as everytime the button was clicked the page was reloading and then when I changed the button type from submit so it wouldn't reload I couldn't retrieve the $_POST attributes from the form